# Puedo subir un archivo al FTP pero luego no puedo eliminarlo porque su nombre contiene caracteres inválidos

Tags: java, spring-boot, ftp, sftp, ftpclient

Estoy trabajando en un programa en Java que gestiona la subida, eliminación, listado, etc.. de archivos a un servidor de FTP.

Me he dado cuenta de que me permite subir un archivo con este nombre:

> Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2, - Descripcion (Remix) [Random Records].mp3

...pero luego no me deja eliminarlo, diciendo que el nombre del archivo contiene caracteres inválidos:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Me resulta raro que me permita subirlo si luego me va a dar problemas. Había pensado en renombrar el archivo, pero es una decisión que no me corresponde.

¿Hay alguna forma de que pueda manipular archivos con nombres "complicados"?

Comment: Quizás eligiendo otra codificación de caracteres...

Comment: Por ahí iba la cosa! Resultó ser culpa mía: Solo debía seleccionar el nombre del archivo que pasaba por postman -> Clic derecho -> Encode. Aún así al final he decidido generar un nombre aleatorio de 12 caracteres para el archivo y guardar en la base de datos ambos nombre. Gracias por tomarte la molestia de ayudarme, Arnau!!

Comment: @Calfa puede que haya pasado mucho tiempo, pero ¡no olvides agregar tu solución como respuesta, y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resultó ser culpa mía:
Solo debía seleccionar el nombre del archivo que pasaba por Postman -> Clic derecho -> Encode. Aún así al final he decidido generar un nombre aleatorio de 12 caracteres para el archivo y guardar en la base de datos ambos nombre.

Gracias a tod@s porla ayuda!